# using vs typedef pointer-to-noexcept-function inconsistency

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I realized that I can declare a type for a pointer to `noexcept` function via `using`, but I am forbidden such declaration if I use a `typedef`. Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using fptr = void(*)() noexcept;
// typedef void(*FPTR)() noexcept; // fails to compile

void f() noexcept
{
    std::cout << "void f() noexcept" << std::endl;
}

void g()
{
    std::cout << "void g()" << std::endl;
    throw 10;
}

int main()
{
    fptr f1 = f;
    fptr f2 = g; // why can we do this?

    try {
        f1();
        f2();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the `FPTR` declaration, I'm getting

> `error: 'FPTR' declared with an exception specification`

However, the `using` works just fine. Compiled with both gcc4.9 and gcc5.

My questions are:

1. Why this inconsistency?
2. Why can we even use `using` with `noexcept` since we can bind the pointer to functions not declared `noexcept`, as in the line `fptr f2 = g;`

---

Seems to be a bug related to gcc, even gcc5 doesn't catch it. Filled a bug report

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65382

Comment: _"I realized that I can declare a pointer to noexcept function via using"_ No you can't. That's a type, not a pointer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes you're right, that's what I meant actually, corrected it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in GCC; Clang rejects both as exception specifications are not allowed in type aliases or `typedef`s. This can be found in:

> #### 15.4 Exception specifications [except.spec]
>
> <sup>2</sup> An *exception-specification* shall appear only on a function declarator for a function type, pointer to function type, reference to function type, or pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of a declaration or definition, or on such a type appearing as a parameter or return type in a function declarator. **An *exception-specification* shall not appear in a typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*.**
>
> [...]

The standard also explicitly says that both should be consistent:

> #### 7.1.3 The `typedef` specifier [dcl.typedef]
>
> <sup>2</sup> A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The identifier following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the identifier appertains to that *typedef-name*. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier**. In particular, it does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the *type-id*.

(emphasis mine)

To answer your second question: GCC probably just ignores the exception specification as functions can not be overloaded on just the exception specification - it is not part of the function's signature. This can be found here:

> #### 8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]
>
> <sup>6</sup> [...] The return type, the parameter-type-list, the *ref-qualifier*, and the *cv-qualifier-seq*, but not the default arguments (8.3.6) or the exception specification (15.4), are part of the function type. [ *Note:* Function types are checked during the assignments and initializations of pointers to functions, references to functions, and pointers to member functions. — *end note* ]

Comment: I filled a bug for gcc5, as I wasn't able to find it in bugzilla.